# Passing entire column to xml

Tags: xml, r

I have an xml file test.xml stored locally on my c:\ that takes parameter value student id as follows

```
.
.
.
<input-id>"student"
        3392966
        </input-id>
```

I have a data frame in R that contains a bunch of student id values

```
    3392966
    4064262
    7319370
    7115327
    . 
    .
    .
```

How can I pass the entire Student Id values stored in the dataset into the test.xml file input-id handle ?

```
.
.
.
<input-id>"student"
        ....All student Id values from the StudentId column from dataframe Test
        </input-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
library("XML")

# test data frame
Test <- data.frame( StudentId = c(100, 200, 300))

# parse XML
doc <- xmlParseDoc("test.xml")

# find first <input-id> element
ns <- getNodeSet(doc, "//input-id")[[1]]

# adding dataframe column StudentId as new sub-elements
kids <- lapply( Test$StudentId, function(x) newXMLNode("id", x) )

addChildren(ns, kids = kids, append = FALSE)

# save XML
saveXML(doc, file = "test2.xml")
```

In this case the IDs will be sub-elements of the input-id element.
If you want to add the xml text nodes use newXMLTextNode instead of newXMLNode.

Comment: I am trying to replace whatever currently exits between the input-id handle with values from `Test$StudentId`. I tried using newXMLTextNode option and i am getting this error....`Error in UseMethod("addChildren") : no applicable method for 'addChildren' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')" Called from: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)` when executing this line `lapply( Test$StudentId, function(x) newXMLNode("id", x) )`..

Comment: Works on my machine :)  - I included my version of the Test data frame in the code snippet. Maybe there are some differences in our data inputs (where is c(int, num) coming from?)

Comment: :-) it works if I manually delete all the contents inside the element `<input-id>.... <input-id>` ...if the `<input-id>` element contains some ids already then the code will not replace for some reason